# Unable to use string functions in REST query

Tags: 2013, rest, string

I am querying for duplication of column name in the web using REST query. My query is as per below:

`http://siteCollection/sites/Project1/_api/Web/Fields?$select=InternalName&$filter=toupper(InternalName) eq 'TITLE'`.

The reference I got from [this](http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Querying-and-exploring-REST-API-with-oData-in-SharePoint-2013-with-DataBase-net.aspx) site. But whenever I am running the same query in the REST Client I am getting following error:

`The function operator 'toupper' is not supported or its usage is invalid.`

What am I missing in my query? Or this is not a way for doing the case insensitive query then which way is preferable?

Comment: If you are looking to find duplicate columns, note that the internal name will always be unique. So I am not sure what exactly you are looking for. The best option is to get all fields and then using JavaScript string functions you can review the same.

Comment: I am providing different GUI to users for creating the field. And prior to creation of field I want to check whether the field is already available or not. That's why I am checking for duplication in the field internal names.@AmalHashim

Answer (score 0):

`toupper` is not supported. Below is the [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385%28v=office.15%29.aspx) of supported functions

[image]

On the other hand if you use `ListData.svc` endpoint you can use `toupper` to perform a similar query.